# Cookies not work angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm get data in $http and put in cookies but not work . Here is my code

services

```
.factory('dataServices',dataServices);




    function dataServices(){

        var cart =[];
            var services = {
                            cart    : cart,
                            addCart : addCart
                }
        return services
                          function addCart(tensp,gia,img,sl){
                            cart.push({tensp:tensp,gia:gia,img:img,sl:sl})
                        }
    }
```

And in js

```
function shopController(dataServices,$cookies){
        var vm=this;
    vm.cart = dataServices.cart;
        vm.add = function(tensp,gia,img){
                        return dataServices.addCart(tensp,gia,img,1);
                        $cookies.put('cart',vm.cart);
                    console.log($cookies.get('cart'))
                    }
}
```

Html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="vm.add(data.tensp,data.gia,data.img)">
                Add to Cart</button>
```

Here is data i want put in cookies . It Json file

```
[{"tensp":"CPU INTEL CORE I5","gia":"400","img":"item14.jpg","sl":1}]
```

But nothing show in console.log . Where is my wrong? Please help me

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, nothing is executed after your `return` statement. Put `$cookies.put('cart','vm.cart'); console.log($cookies.get('cart'));` before your `return` statement. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$cookies.put('cart',vm.cart);`?

Comment: @eminlala i use this , and now i help vm.cart in my cookies but not the data i want

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (remove single quotes around `vm.cart`):

```
function shopController(dataServices,$cookies){
        var vm=this;
    vm.cart = dataServices.cart;
        vm.add = function(tensp,gia,img){
                          //first add data to dataServices.cart 
                          dataServices.addCart(tensp,gia,img,1);   

                          //then add it to $cookies                     
                          $cookies.putObject('cart',vm.cart);
                          console.log($cookies.getObject('cart'))
                    }
}
```

Since your `vm.data` is an object, you should use `putObject` and `getObject` methods.When you try to get the value from the `$cookies`, you will have to do this:

```
var val = $cookies.getObject('cart'));
```

Comment: Okay, I see now  that `vm.cart` is not just a `string` value. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I try it but now I get error `Unexpected token v in JSON`

Comment: I edited question . Data i want put is json file . How can i do that

Comment: I have edited the answer. You will have to use `$cookies.putObject` and `$cookies.getObject`.

Comment: thank you . But now i have empty array in console.log

Comment: That's because you print out content of that cookie before you have added it to `dataService.cart`. I will add this too in my answer.

Comment: omg thank you . I get it in console.log . But now I want display it in html . I try like this  `vm.cookies =$cookies.getObject('cart')` and it have error `Unexpected token v in JSON`